# Git remove file from repo without deleting WHEN OTHERS PULL

Tags: git, gitignore, git-rm

Each developer in my team has an .idea file in the root of their local working copy. Somebody didn't have it in their global .gitignore (and it's not in any other .gitignores) so they've accidentally committed it to our remote repo. Now it is being tracked.

We want to un-track it again but we need the .idea files to remain on **every** local machine. The canonical suggestion is to `git rm -r --cache .idea` and then push to the remote, but while this leaves the .idea directory on the machine on which the command is run, .idea will still get deleted from others' machines next time they pull. This has been mentioned across the many similar questions but only in comments etc. and there's only a range of hacky workarounds that require every developer taking some action to avoid the deletion. This is infeasible for a large or dispersed team, and in any case feels inappropriate given the *only* change we want to action is on the repo history, not local filesystems. Put the tracking status of the .idea directory back to how it was - untracked, and git leaves it alone.

What is the canonical or best practice way to achieve this?

Comment: If you are using Maven then tell people they need to reimport the project.  Done.

(Also this is what branches and peer review is for)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen "tell people they need to..." - as per the question I am trying to avoid this

Comment: Have they puhsed their local copy yet?

Comment: You know you can force push to an earlier commit?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I hadn't considered it (only rudimental git user), but if you're suggesting rolling back history to before the bad commit, I've no idea how long the mistake has been in this repo and other changes have been committed to the branch since then. Thanks for your suggestions though

Comment: You can always ask git for the history of a specific file. This can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Commit where the file was pushed and tracked can be reverted as @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen said. I am not very experienced reverting commits so I would be a bit scared about that, more if there are several important commits after that one. However an experienced git user should not have problem with that. As I'm not I would XD.
One thing I succesfully did when I uploaded many files to my repo I did not want to track (due to poor gitignore handling) was to set a new origin to the repo with the erased files and the updated .gitignore, then you set the new upstream origin to your local branch, so your local repo will be now tracked against the new origin. To sum up, mi point is to upload the repo to the cloud according to the status you want and set the new origin. Find the link:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url

Maybe its a noob solution, however for me worked like a charm and as the project was not big, the fix was not very time consuming, moreover in case there might be any problem, you would have your original repo/origin available as a backup.
Hope that helps